# Is it possible to unselect <Radio /> by clicking selected one (in React)?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, forms, input

Is it possible to unselect radio by clicking a selected one?

I know this is default browser behavior, but I've been working on this custom feature.

[Material-ui](https://material-ui.com/demos/selection-controls/) can't do this too.

I know [Material-ui](https://material-ui.com/demos/selection-controls/) wraps `<input type="radio">` inside `<label />`, it looks like this:

```
<label>
  <input type="radio" onChange={() => {}}>
</label>
```

If I want to implement this feature, I will have to replace `onChange` into `onClick`, but then the browser will yell at me that `<input />` should have `onChange` event handler.

So how do I properly hook `onChange` along with `onClick` event handler?

Should I just give `onChange` event an empty function? Or should I call `preventDefault`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-kbdr85) url

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import Hello from './Hello';
import './style.css';

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      group1:[{"value":"1"},
      {"value":"2"},
      {"value":"3"}],
      group1Selected:null,
      group2:[{"value":"1"},
      {"value":"2"},
      {"value":"3"}],
       group2Selected:null,
    };
  }
  ChangeOption = (i,group) =>{
    var groupData = this.state[group] == i?null:i;        
    this.setState({[group]:groupData})
  }
  render() {
    const {group1,group2,group1Selected,group2Selected} = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        {
          group1.map( (data,i)=><><input type="radio" id={`1-${i}`} onClick={e=>this.ChangeOption(i,"group1Selected")} checked={i==group1Selected?true:false} name="1" value={data.value}/><label for={`1-${i}`}>{data.value}</label></>)
        }
        <br/>
        {
          group2.map( (data,i)=><><input id={`2-${i}`} onClick={e=>this.ChangeOption(i,"group2Selected")} type="radio" checked={i==group2Selected?true:false} name="2" value={data.value}/><label for={`2-${i}`}>{data.value}</label></>)
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: But the code has no `onChange` event handler, the browser will yell at accessibility.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out kindly check https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-kbdr85 url